# Google Sheets formula time roundup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this is my formula i've right now.

```
=AUFRUNDEN($H$1*24;0)/24
```

H1 formula = JETZT()
https://prnt.sc/stlmrh
Result : 13:00

My problem where I stuck is, how I can roundup the time to 12:59, 13:59, 14:59 and so on. Would be nice for the right formula if this is possible.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `NOW()` function returns the current time and day and is normally displayed in the local date format, e.g. DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss. Behind the format is a number though, and that number is days since 30 December 1899 (e.g. today has the value 43,986, how many days since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing))). Then you have decimals to signify the time during the day, e.g. 43,986.5 is today at noon.

You can use this to tweak your formula to find the applicable multiplier for the number of decimals needed.

..or..

if you just want the result to be one minute before the hour, you can use your formula and deduct one minute using `=TIME(0,1,0)`, which I guess is `=ZEIT(0,1,0)` in German.

Answer (score 0):

I found for my question the perfect solution. It works fine as I want it

```
=text(A1;"hh:59")
```

This code roundsup =now() with the current timezone + 59. for example

it's now ( 23:46 ) code below round it up to 23:59, so when it is 00:01 it goes to 00:59.
So if anyone need it, hope it helps some one.